# SQL limit results in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Assuming I have the following table :

```
Table Files
 id
 size
```

In pseudo SQL I need this king of processing :

```
select id
where
size < S1 and (limit this clause to N1 results)
or
size > S2 and (limit this clause to N2 results)
```

I know Oracle defines rownum keyword to limit results.

But in my case, that does not work.

Do this require subselects ? How ? Is that possible to use multiple subselects ?

(This SQL would be generated by a java program with other where clauses, making the use of subselects difficult..)

Edit:
I need to filter more than just different size.

SOLVED

```
SELECT * 
FROM Files
WHERE
    someField = 'stuff'
AND
    someOtherField = 'other stuff'
AND
(
    SELECT id FROM Files WHERE size <= S1 AND ROWNUM <= N1
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM Files WHERE size > S2 AND ROWNUM <= N2
)
```

Comment: Yes, N is a number of results

Comment: In your edit, why are you comparing `size` to two different numbers? I thought `N1` and `N2` were the number of results to return, not sizes.

Comment: You're right, fixed it. My example is not very nice, since the original problem is way complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'low' AS "which", "id"
    FROM Files
    WHERE "size" < S1)
WHERE ROWNUM <= N1

UNION

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'high' AS "which", "id"
    FROM Files
    WHERE "size" >= S1)
WHERE ROWNUM <= N2
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc7e9/7)

Comment: @ObscurMoirage I've revised the answer to use Oracle syntax, and tested it at sqlfiddle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff indeed it was an Oracle SQL question. I guess i've lost everyone when using the term "limit" which is also a MySQL keyword.
Thanks for your changes Barmar

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the clauses are *independent* (which they are for your example), you can do this with `union all`:

```
select id
. . .
where size < S1 and rownum <= N1
union all
select id
. . .
where size > S1 and rownum <= N2
```

If you don't want to repeat the `from` clause (because it is complex for instance), you can use a CTE:

```
with t as (<blah blah blah>)
select *
from ((select id from t where size < S1 and rownum <= N1) union all
      (select id from t where size > S1 and rownum <= N2)
     ) x
```

Comment: Whats the difference between UNION and UNION ALL ?

Comment: `UNION` removes duplicates, `UNION ALL` leaves them in. They're equivalent in this case, since the IDs are from disjoint subsets of the data. But `ALL` should make the query more efficient, since it doesn't have to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Files
WHERE
    someField = 'stuff'
AND
    someOtherField = 'other stuff'
AND
(
    SELECT id FROM Files WHERE size <= N1  AND ROWNUM <= N1
    UNION
    SELECT id FROM Files WHERE size  > N2  AND ROWNUM <= N2
)
```